# RethinkDB, query with map and filter

Tags: python, rethinkdb

I have rethinkdb 'competition' table. At the second level I got runners and each runner have a list of results:

```
"total_results": {
  "433915": [  #runner_id
    {
      "judge": "15561671",
      "result": 5,
      "round": "1"
    },
    {
      "judge": "08136a59",
      "result": 4,
      "round": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

I do rethinkdb query:

```
results = (r.table('competitions').filter(lambda c: c['unique_id'] == competition_id)
    .map(lambda c: c['total_results'])
    .map(lambda t: t[runner_id])
.run(conn))
```

This piece of code works fine. Now I want to apply filter based on 'round' value. I add it right after the second .map() so results query looks like:

```
results = (r.table('competitions').filter(lambda c: c['unique_id'] == competition_id)
    .map(lambda c: c['total_results'])
    .map(lambda t: t[runner_id])
    .filter(lambda x: x['round'] == round)
.run(conn))
```

But I'm getting empty list. And this is strange for me because if I move .filter() outside of rethinkdb query and do it like:

```
by_round = filter(lambda x: x['round'] == round, results)
```

I get results.
There should be something I'm doing wrong in rethink query... Can you give me a tip please?

p.s. I have thousands results in the database. There should be dozens results based on my query params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want your second `map` to be a `concat_map`.  (Alternatively, if you like the existing output format, you can put the `filter` inside a `map` like `.map(lambda x: x.filter(...))`.)

Comment: Hi @mlucy, thank you very much for reply! Yes, you were right, replacing my second map with concat_map did the job. Could you please replace concatMap to concat_map in your answer (python-way)? I'll mark you answer as "accepted".